# what are the default arguments for setAutoThreshold() in batch mode?

Tags: imagej

I hope you can help me, and that this is the appropriate forum to ask (I have tried on the group letter, but it didnt seem like my message was forwarded). I have inherited some code, which I would like to rewrite. The code consists of a macro that has batchmode set to true, and calls setAutoThreshold(). I have only found setAutoThreshold with 5 different signatures as a method attached to ImageProcessor, none of which have void (no input arguments) as signature. I thus suspect that the batchmode or the macro itself sets some default arguments in the background.

What are the defaults for setAutoThreshold (how would I translate setAutoThreshold() to one that setAutoThreshold(ARGUMENTS_HERE)?
and it works on the imageProcessor of the current image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [macro documentation](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html) describes the arguments that can be used:

> **setAutoThreshold()** Uses the "Default" method to determine the
>   threshold. It may select dark or bright areas as thresholded, as was
>   the case with the Image>Adjust>Threshold "Auto" option in ImageJ 1.42o
>   and earlier. See also: setThreshold, getThreshold, resetThreshold.
>
> **setAutoThreshold(method)** Uses the specified method to set the
>   threshold levels of the current image. Use the
>   getList("threshold.methods") function to get a list of the available
>   methods. Concatenate " dark" to the method name if the image has a
>   dark background. For an example, see the [AutoThresholdingDemo](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/macros/examples/AutoThresholdingDemo.txt) macro.

If you're interested in how the thresholds are calculated, the default AutoThreshold method is explained in the [ImageJ FAQ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/faqs.html#auto) and the documentation [wiki](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=faq:technical:what_is_the_algorithm_used_in_automatic_thresholding).  You can also read the source code to find out how the calculations are done.

I hope this answers your question. You might also try the ImageJ [forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: i think maybe it does. In a java-file could I write setAutoTreshold("Default") as the same as a macro setAutoTreshold()? (I will check tomorrow)

Comment: i think maybe it does. In a java-file could I write setAutoTreshold("Default") as the same as a macro setAutoTreshold()? for instance IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default") (where imp is of type ImagePlus, I will check tomorrow)

Comment: Oh, now I see you want to write a Java plugin. I was thinking of the macro language. The forum should be a good source for that.